# Temporarily change current directory in Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, fabric

I would like to run multiple commands need to be (or is easier to be) in another directory, then once they're done, return back to the previous working directory.

I'm envisioning something similar to [Fabric's `with cd(path):`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd), e.g.:

```
cd('.git') do
   File.unlink('config')
end
```

Is there an inbuilt way of doing this in Rake, or should I be writing a custom method that accepts a block, etc.?

Comment: This pattern isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is simply the inbuilt `Dir#chdir` call:

```
Dir.chdir('.git') do
  File.unlink('config')
end
```

Excerpt from the [docs](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Dir.html):

> If a block is given, it is passed the name of the new current directory, and the block
>   is executed with that as the current directory. The original working
>   directory is restored when the block exits.